# How custom Account Repository become a bean without any annotation ?

Tags: java, spring

I customized the spring security for my spring boot app.

I use a custom Account Repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import com.boot.cut_costs.config.security.CustomUserDetails;

public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomUserDetails, String>{
    public CustomUserDetails findByUsername(String username);
}
```

As you can see, I don't use any annotation for it. But in other classes, I can access it as a bean ? how is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using spring boot and your `main` application class in a root package above other classes then the bean classes will be scanned and detected automatically and you can look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html) on this.

> The `@SpringBootApplication` annotation is equivalent to using
>   `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan`.
>   Also, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation implicitly defines a base
>   “search package” for certain items.

Comment: 1. But I never used it anywhere. I used `@SpringBootApplication` and `@EnableWebSecurity` in other classes, though. 2. What is the meaning of "the package of annotated configuration class" ?

Comment: So, basically it means it searches for an interface that implements `JpaRepository` even if it is not annotated, right ?

Comment: Also, note that the implementation for the interface is anyhow provided by the spring container during startup

Answer (score 1):

Check out this annotation `@EnableJpaRepositories`. You may be using it as a class level annotation on one of your `@Configuration` class.

From the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.7.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html)

> Annotation to enable JPA repositories. Will scan the package of the annotated configuration class for Spring Data repositories by default.

Example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"xxx.xxx.xxx.core.dao"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig{

}
```

Comment: Well, I don't use it and it works ! My question was how/why it works if it's not annotated.

Comment: You are not using `@EnableJpaRepositories` on any of your configuration classes?

Comment: No, it's not used anywgere.

Comment: Since you are using `@SpringBootApplication` it works.